# using message collector to collect for an embed

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, collectors

I am trying to change an embed command. What I want is when someone types the command in for the bot to ask what would you like to embed, then when the users respond the both then posts it as an embed. this is what I have however VSC using typescript says there is a missing. Where does the comma go or am I using the wrong function?

```
if(msgObject.content.startsWith(-embed)){
        msgObject.channel.send('What would you like to embed?')

        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(msgObject.channel, m => m.author.id === msgObject.author.id, { time: 1000000 });

        collector.on('collect', message => {
            if(!message.content === null)
            return;

            let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor(Random)
            .setDescription(message)
            .setThumbnail(msgObject.author.avatarURL)
            .setFooter(msgObject.author.username)
            .setTimestamp();

            msgObject.delete(70)// Waits 70 Milliseconds and deletes the message sent by the user.

            msgObject.channel.send(embed) // Sends the new message

        }
    }
```